# UE4 C++ variables inside function are null

Tags: c++, function, class, unreal-engine4

Trying to call a function from another class in Unreal Engine 4. I have two classes, an AActor and a UWidget class, Im calling a function in AActor class from UWidget class. (So UWidget has an instance in AActor)

Now when I call the function, it runs without problems, I can even print debug message on screen without errors, however if I want to use ANY variable in that function, it returns null.

For example I create a variable inside UWIdget .h give it a value in UWidget .cpp and when I want to print that variable value it just gives back 0.

Calling the function in AActor
[image: UpdateInventoryBarSlot is the function I'm calling from UWidget class]

UpdateInventoryBarSlot is the function I'm calling from UWidget class

UpdateInventoryBarSlot function inside UWidget
[image: UpdateInventoryBarSlot function]

The variables are not null IF I run it inside the class, running it out of that class in another class results in undefined values. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the .h file so I'll make an assumption that you didn't wrap your variables with `UPROPERTY()` macro so variable could be erased by unreal garbage collector.

Also i see a `Destroy()` method on the 3d line on 1st screenshot. Make sure that you destroy correct actor and you don't use this actor or any data inside of it after calling this method.

Comment: I made a github repo to store the relevant files, you can check the full code there (https://github.com/Nechalon/UnrealEngineDebugging1). I think I added UPROPERTY() everywhere where its needed, but will check it later again.

The destroy function does not have anything to do with the function because it runs the same if I remove it.